# Dynamic content using Asset Publisher and tags

Tags: tags, liferay, liferay-6

I'm pretty sure this can be done, but am finding little documentation on how to do it correctly.

I have several Web Content pieces that I've associated with tags. I'd like to add an Asset Publisher portlet to a page that displays the correct Web Content based on if a tag exists in the URL. So if the url is: domain.com/public/site?tag=fish then it serves up the Web Content tagged "fish"using the Asset Publisher filter.

What is the correct syntax for the URL? I've seen in forums:

/public/site/tags/fish/ and I've seen it as a parameter ?tag=fish but neither of these seem to work. I'm using Liferay 6.

Answer (score 1):

See the TagNavigation or TagCloud portlet and how they construct their URLs - AFAIK they use public render parameters.

Comment: Where can I find their source code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this syntax in the url `/web/mysite/mypage/tags/mytag` 
It works for Liferay 5.2.3. Of course you need an Asset Publisher on the page "mypage" of the community "mysite" and some content which is tagged with "mytag".